# Selenium C# wait until does not work with user profile

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using c# Selenium web driver for automatic login process. Basically I want to skip the login process and land user directly on home page. I am using selenium automation for this.There is password element on the page for that I have to add wait. I am using below
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element);
It works perfectly fine. But as soon as I load chrome driver with user profile it does not work. I am adding below to run chromedriver under existing user profile on system.

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments(@“- - user - data -dir=C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data”)

IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Chrome starts with user profile. But wait does work.

Thanks